# What is a SLOT()SLOT() member

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to use the following to add an option to a custom right-click context menu in a QsciScintilla textEdit window:

```
fileMenu.addAction(self.ui.textEdit_one.tr("&Get"), self, self.addToConfig)
```

where addToConfig is a method, or "slot" for my application.
fileMenu expects the following format:

```
QAction QMenu.addAction (self, QString text, QObject receiver, SLOT()SLOT() member, QKeySequence shortcut = 0)
```

I've tried using many combinations of QtCore.SLOT('self.addToConfig()'), but can't seem to get the correct format.

I keep getting variations of:

```
QMenu.addAction(QString, QObject, SLOT(), QKeySequence shortcut=0): argument 3 has unexpected type 'instancemethod'
```

or

```
Object::connect: No such slot StartQT4::addToConfig()
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'EditorWindow')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix old style signals/slots with new style signals/slots. For old style connections, you would pass in the object (`self`) as one parameter, and the next would be, in your case, `SLOT('addToConfig(<arg types...>)')`.

However, you should just use new style connections, which means simply calling `fileMenu.addAction(self.ui.textEdit_one.tr("&Get"), self.addToConfig)`, see: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenu.html#addAction-5

Comment: I don't think I understood the "receiver" field correctly. QAction QMenu.addAction (self, QString text, callable receiver, QKeySequence shortcut = 0) worked great thank you!

Comment: Yep, in the original signature you tried, it was looking for a receiver of type `QObject` (aka an object, not a method) where as the signature you are now using is expecting a receiver of type `callable` (aka a method). Anyway, glad I could help!